# Is overriding dispose() without super.dispose() efficent?

Tags: flutter, dart

I was getting **Unhandled Exception: Once you have called dispose() it can no longer be used.** error in my viewmodel class after changing the provider. After some research, my solution was overriding dispose in my viewmodel class but not returning the super.dispose() like this:

```
  bool _mounted = false;
  bool get mounted => _mounted;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _mounted = true;
  }
```

This solution works fine, but there is a question mark in my head. As I understand, even I dispose the object, It still remains in the tree. So my question is firstly, did I understand that correctly, if not, what this solution is really doing? Secondly, if it still remains in the tree, does that cause any memory use inefficency? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After object disposal you SHOUDL NOT use the object (view model in the case) anymore.
Your current situation is that the view model has been disposed somwhere, but you still want to use it.
What you can do is:

- dont dispose the object
- create a **NEW** object

You should DEFINITELY NOT use object that has been disposed because it has been disposed for some reason. There may be a situation that it has been patrially disposed and it may lead to errors / exceptions which may be hard to debug.

You should read about Disposable pattern.

Comment: I have a sidemenu which has a profile and to-do screen. When my to-do is in loading state and I click to profile to go to profile page, I get the error. So, If I create a new object instead disposing it, does that mean everytime I switch to profile to to-do screen a new object will be created? When I switch to profile screen back, will the object be deleted?